# unable to delete array key from multidimensional array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays

I want to delete array index which contain rating 0 here is my array

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Gig' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'rating' => (int) 5
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Gig' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'rating' => (int) 9
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Gig' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'rating' => '0'
        )
    )
)
```

and what I did

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($agetGigsItem); $i++)
{
if($agetGigsItem[$i]['Gig']['rating']==0)
{
unset($agetGigsItem[$i]);   
}
$this->set('agetGigsItem', $agetGigsItem);
}
```

i also try foreach loop but unable to resolve this issue.

```
foreach ($agetGigsItem as $key => $value) { 

    if ($value["Gig"]["rating"] == 0) { unset($agetGigsItem[$key]); }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your seconds code? ([Works fine!](http://3v4l.org/mHKBm))

Comment: maybe because it is a string and youre giving an integer value to compare with? `if($agetGigsItem[$i]['Gig']['rating']=='0')`

Comment: Are you sure you accepted the correct answer here? You told @AtaboyJosef his answer fixed your problems but accepted an answer that does not remove the item from the array properly

Comment: @RiggsFolly @ Ataboy Josef resolved my problem i got what i need

Comment: Good, So that why I mentioned it, because you had ticked the wrong answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reupdate your array.

```
foreach ($agetGigsItem as $key => $value) {
if ($value["Gig"]["rating"] != 0) 
{
unset($agetGigsItem[$key]); 
}
$this->set('agetGigsItem', $agetGigsItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are missing `$this` and so you cannot access the array in CakePHP.

So try this:

```
foreach ($this->$agetGigsItem as $key => $value) { 
    if ($value["Gig"]["rating"] == 0) {
      unset($this->$agetGigsItem[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will unset arrey index with value 0.

```
<?php

$array=array(
array(
    'Gig' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'rating' =>5
    )
),
array(
    'Gig' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'rating' =>9
    )
),
array(
    'Gig' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'rating' =>0
    )
)
);

foreach($array as $a){

if($a['Gig']['rating']==0){

    unset($a['Gig']['rating']);

}

$array1[]=$a;

}

var_dump($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroying occurances within an array you are actually processing over with a `for` or a `foreach` is always a bad idea. Each time you destroy an occurance the loop can easily get corrupted and get in a terrible mess.

If you want to remove items from an array it is better to create a copy of the array and process over that new array in the loop but remove the items from the original array.

So try this instead

```
$tmparray = $this->agetGigsItem;   // will copy agetGigsItem into new array

foreach ($tmparray as $key => $value) { 
    if ($value["Gig"]["rating"] == 0) { 
        unset($this->agetGigsItem[$key]); 
    }
}
unset($tmparray);
```